Upper and lower bounds on rowlands sequence
Rowlands sequence is defined as follows
\begin{equation}
a_{n}=a_{n-1} + b_{n}
\end{equation}
where $b_{n} = \gcd(a_{n-1}, n)$ for $n>h$.
It originates from $E$. Rowlands 2008 paper "A Natural Prime-Generating Recurrence".
What upper and lower bounds exists for $a_{n}$?
I managed to prove $a_{n} < Cn$ for a constant $C$ depending on $h$ by substituting the $gcd-lcm$ identity into the above equation and then substituting that equation into itself into getting the following and bounding it from above
$$a_{n} = a_{h}\prod_{i=h+1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{i}{\operatorname{lcm}\left(a_{i-1},\ i\right)}\right)$$
but from numerical data it seems $\frac{3}2(n+1)\le a_{n} \le 3n$ are the best bounds for any initial condition where $a_{h}>h$.
Remark: showing that bound is equivalent to showing
$$
\frac{3}2h\prod_{i=h}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)\le a_{h}\prod_{i=h+1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{i}{\operatorname{lcm}\left(a_{i-1},\ i\right)}\right)\le3h\prod_{i=h}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)
$$
What potential ways could the bounds be derived?

Note: You cross-posted this about an hour earlier on MathOverflow at upper and lower bounds on rowlands sequence. Please note that cross-posting is generally frowned on if it's done so relatively quickly (I've read that it's recommended to wait at least a week before possibly doing so). At the minimum, though, please at least mention that you've done so in your question text, and include a link to the other post, to help minimize issues like duplication of efforts.
